# Lattice isomorphism between $(\{A \subset \mathbb{N} : A$ is finite$\}, \cup, \cap)$ and $(\mathbb{N},lcm,gcd)$.

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

My problem is to know if there exists a lattice isomorphism between $B = (\{A \subset \mathbb{N} : A$ is finite$\}, \cup, \cap)$ and $C = (\mathbb{N},lcm,gcd)$. I think that is posible because have the same cardinality ($\mathbb{N}$), both have a minimum ($\emptyset$ and 1 respectively) and neither have maximum.

I tried to define a function (candidate to isomorphism) from B to A starting sending $\emptyset$ to the 1 and the sets of one element to the primes "in order" ($\{1\}$ to 2, $\{2\}$ to 3, $\{3\}$ to 5, ...) and then I need to define that sends the $\{1,2\}$ to 2*3=6 and so on. But that function isn't a surjection.

I also know that is enough to find a bijective homomorphism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wikipedia [notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Connection_between_the_two_definitions) the algebraic and order-theoretic definitions of lattices are equivalent, so we may as well discuss if there is an order isomorphism from $(\mathcal{P}_{\mathrm{fin}}(\mathbb{N}),\subseteq)$ and $(\mathbb{N},\mid )$.

The answer is no, for $(\mathbb{N},\mid )$ has elements that cover one atom but no other atoms (squares of primes) and $(\mathcal{P}_{\mathrm{fin}}(\mathbb{N}),\subseteq)$ doesn't (it's not possible for a set to strictly contain one singleton set but no other singleton sets).

It's kind of like comparing $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ to $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ with lexicographic orderings, except your two lattices are sublattices of these comprised of functions with finite support.

Comment: Beat me to it! It's worth pointing out that $\mathbb{P}_{fin}(\mathbb{N})$ is isomorphic to the squarefree numbers under divisibility though.

Comment: Or that $\mathbb{N}$ is isomorphic to the finite "multisubsets" of $\mathbb{N}$ (like subsets but where elements are allowed to have multiplicities).